# How to optimize a trained Tensorflow graph for execution speedup?

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, deep-learning, openvino, tensorflow-xla

in order to do fast CPU inference of a frozen Tensorflow graph (.pb) I am currently using Tensorflow's C API. The inference speed is already fairly good, however (compared to CPU-specific tools like Intel's OpenVINO) I have so far no possibility to somehow optimize the graph before running it. I am interested in any sort of optimization that is suitable:
- device-specific optimization for CPU
- graph-specific optimization (fusing operations, dropping out nodes, ...)
- ... and everything else lowering the time required for inference.

Therefore I am looking for a way to optimize graphs after training and before execution. As mentioned, Tools like Intel's OpenVINO (for CPUs) and NVIDIA's TensorRT (for GPUs) do stuff like that. I am also working with OpenVINO but currently waiting for a bug fix so that I would like to try an additional way.

I thought about trying Tensorflow XLA, but I have no experience using it. Moreover I have to make sure to either get a frozen graph (.pb) or something that I can convert to a frozen graph (e.g. .h5) in the end.

I would be grateful for recommendations!

Greets

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps:

1. freeze tensorflow trained model (frozen_graph.pb) - for that you may required trained model .pb, checkpoints & output node names
2. optimize your frozen model with Intel OpenVINO model optimizer -

> python3 mo.py --input_model frozen_graph.pb

Additionally you may required `input_shape`

3. you will get .xml & .bin files as result. with the help of benchmark_app, you can check inference optimisation .